# How to Find The Sugar Bomb

Tags: another-case-solved

How do you find the bomb in the chapter 4 - Bombing the Ballad. I've searched every room on the left hand side, but can't figure out how to get past the room with all the bookshelves.

Answer (score 1):

I had to play "bombing the ballot" three times to figure it out. The second time I got lucky, but there had to be an answer on the map. There is.

> There are three alarm boxes, and you need the two on the left to get past rooms. Once you do, you come to the library (which is not marked) but your detective says, "This looks like the place they made the bomb". Look at all the items in that room - you will see a fuse, tool case and a yellow wire. That will be the wire to cut to deactivate the bomb.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ladder on the chimney to go to the right side.

Comment: The only chimney I found doesn't have a ladder as a choice

Answer (score -4):

I don't know which level you are in, but you probably need to find the book that "moves" the shelf, so you can find a hidden passage.